# Show that $ \operatorname{Sp}(1)=\{A \in M_1(\mathbb{H})\mid AA^*=I=A^*A\}=S^3 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, matrices, group-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $M_n(\mathbb{H})$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with entries in the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$.

For $A=(a_{ij} ) $ let $ A^*=(a^*_{ij} ) $ be the matrix with $a^*_{ij}=\bar{a}_{ij}  $, where $a \bar{x} $ denotes the quaternion conjugate of $x \in \mathbb{H} $. Let:

$$ \operatorname{Sp}(n)=\{A \in M_n(\mathbb{H})\mid AA^*=I=A^*A\} $$

> Show that $\operatorname{Sp}(1)=S^3$

$$ \operatorname{Sp}(1)=\{A \in M_1(\mathbb{H})\mid AA^*=I=A^*A\} $$

$M_1(\mathbb{H})$ is the set of all $1 \times 1$ matrices with entries in the quarernions $\mathbb{H} $

The quarternions satisfy $\mathbb{H} \simeq \mathbb{R^4} $

Well, $Sp(1)$ is the set of all matrices $\{a_i\}$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{H}$, which is just a set of numbers

How can we relate this to $S^3$?

Comment: You have the wrong definition of $\mathbb{H}$ here. The quaternion group that you describe exists, but it's not what your statement is about. It's about the Hamilton quaternions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

Comment: @CaptainLama Oh, I see. I have edited the question

Comment: You just need to examine what it means for a quaternion $x$ to satisfy $x \overline{x} =1$.